# MySql Stored Procedure -> Variable or condition declaration after cursor or handler declaration

Tags: mysql, procedure, declare

i try to create a stored procedure but get always a error when saving. I've tried the declaration in different orders but get the same error or the workbench closes without error.

This procedure should save the datedif from different fields in different tables to one table. another stored procedure should then write "actual" dates in this fields after restoring the databse from a backup. this should be for a Demo Database

the backup table 'datedifs' contains

```
'datedifs', 'tabelle', 'varchar(200)'
'datedifs', 'feld', 'varchar(200)'
'datedifs', 'idfeld', 'varchar(200)'
'datedifs', 'idwert', 'varchar(200)'
'datedifs', 'DateDif', 'int(11) unsigned'
'datedifs', 'bemerkung', 'varchar(400)'
```

and here the code

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `dumpDateDiffs` ()
BEGIN
  DECLARE idFeld VARCHAR(30);
  DECLARE cursor_i CURSOR FOR SELECT TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME, COLUMN_TYPE from information_schema.columns WHERE (Column_Type LIKE '%time%' or Column_Type LIKE '%date%') AND TABLE_SCHEMA = 'pldemo' 
                   AND TABLE_NAME IN ('angebote', 'ansprechpartner', 'benutzer', 'kontaktblog', 'projekte', 'rechnungen','saetzealt','stundenint');
  DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
  DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;
  DELETE FROM datedifs WHERE NOT tabelle IS NULL;
  OPEN cursor_i;
  read_loop: LOOP
    FETCH cursor_i INTO cursor_TABLE_NAME, cursor_COLUMN_NAME, cursor_COLUMN_TYPE;
    IF done THEN
      LEAVE read_loop;
    END IF;
    /**INSERT INTO table_B(ID, VAL) VALUES(cursor_ID, cursor_VAL);**/
    CASE cursor_TABLE_NAME 
      WHEN 'angebote' then SET idfeld = 'ID_Angebot'; SET idfeld2 = ''; 
      WHEN 'ansprechpartner' then SET idfeld = 'idAnsprechpartner'; 
      WHEN 'benutzer' then SET idfeld = 'uid';
      WHEN 'kontaktblog' then SET idfeld = 'ID'; 
      WHEN 'projekte' then SET idfeld = 'prnum'; 
      WHEN 'rechnungen' then SET idfeld = 'id'; 
      WHEN 'saetzealt' then SET idfeld = 'datedifID'; 
      WHEN 'stundenint' then SET idfeld = 'datedifID'; 
      ELSE  SET idfeld = ''; INSERT INTO datedifs (tabelle, feld, idfeld, idwert, DateDif) VALUES('idFeld-Fehler',  cursor_TABLE_NAME);
    END CASE;    
    IF idfeld <> '' then
       INSERT INTO datedifs (tabelle, feld, idfeld, idwert, DateDif) 
                   SELECT '''' + cursor_TABLE_NAME + '''' as 'tabelle', '''' + cursor_COLUMN_NAME + '''' AS 'feld', '''' + idfeld + '''' as 'idfeld', idfeld as 'idwert', DATEDIFF(NOW(),cursor_COLUMN_NAME) AS 'DateDif'
                   FROM cursor_TABLE_NAME WHERE NOT cursor_COLUMN_NAME IS NULL;
    END IF;
    /**INSERT INTO datedifs (tabelle, feld, idfeld, idwert, DateDif) VALUES(cursor_TABLE_NAME, cursor_COLUMN_NAME, cursor_VAL);**/
    /**INSERT INTO datedifs VALUES(cursor_TABLE_NAME, cursor_COLUMN_NAME, cursor_VAL);**/
  END LOOP;
  CLOSE cursor_i;    
END
```

can anyone help?

many many thanks for every tip ;)

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things to start with:

1. Last `DECLARE`'s should be the `DECLARE cursor_i` and `DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER` (move `DECLARE done` before cursor declaration).
2. You need to decalare variables `cursor_*` (3 of them) and `idfeld`
3. You cannot `SELECT` from a variable. You have to use dynamic SQL for that